# Change TCP wait for ACK timeouts in Win7/WinServer

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, windows-registry

Is there any possibility to change default wait for ACK timeout in TCP network on Windows 7 or Windows Server ?

I'm using **very** slow network ( 1200 bps ) and want to tweak TCP. When using default parameters network stuck on multiple retransmissions . If I'm able to change the ACK timeout and tx window size I think that it would work.

On Windows XP it was possible but cant find any document for Win7 and Win Server.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of links that may be helpful in your situation:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Q_28353794.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170359

This article is actually the opposite problem (he's trying to use a big pipe) but doing the inverse of some of the settings might help:  https://www.duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html